# Open Trip Planner 2 - Does it support planning many trips at once?

Tags: opentripplanner

I'm trying to create a dashboard that simulates the usage of a public transport network for a city by planning many trips at once for a set of different origins, destinations and times.

Does Open Trip Planner 2 support sending multiple plan requests to the server at once or would this require the server to be cloud-hosted for scalability? I'm trying to keep this running locally for now.

I notice there is an `AsyncGraphQLFetchers` config item but I am not using GraphQL within this project.

I looked through the docs and only found one /plan route without any option for routing more than a single trip.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution? I'm also trying to achieve same thing

Comment: You can submit a bunch of different plan queries in one GraphQL query, if you decide to use that. On the backend, it won't be processed in a more efficient way than just submitting a bunch of plan queries using the REST API though.